# Referencing form data to php script and inserting it into database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, email

Okay, I've looked everywhere. To begin with I have a form, a newsletter, that users enter their email into. Once they hit submit it checks a php form that takes that email and inputs it into an SQL database that stores the email. The problem is I get this error when submitting the form

`Error: INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES (random@yahoo.com)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@yahoo.com)' at line 2`

No idea why it wont put it into the database. The form code is

```
 <section>
            <div class="mockup-content">
                <div class="morph-button morph-button-inflow morph-button-inflow-1">
                    <button type="button"><span>Subscribe to our Newsletter</span></button>
                    <div class="morph-content">
                        <div>
                            <div class="content-style-form content-style-form-4">
                                <h2 class="morph-clone">Subscribe to our Newsletter</h2>
                                <form action="scripts/mailer.php" method="post">
                                    <p><input type="text" class="button" id="email" name="email" placeholder="NAME@EXAMPLE.COM">
                                    <div>We promise, we won't send you any spam. Just love.</div>
    <input type="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="SIGN UP"></p>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- morph-button -->
            </div>
        </section>
```

This is just the html data for the form, the php data is

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mysql";
$email = ($_POST["email"]);


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }

 $sql = "INSERT INTO emails (email)
  VALUES ($email)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
 } else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }

$conn->close();
?>
```

Can anyone explaine why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a tick (`'`) when binding variables in a query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES ('$email')";
```

It is okay not to use tick when the value of your variable you are trying to bind is an `int`.

Comment: Hey thanks! It works now! So simple! I'd vote up but I cant, anyways thanks! It works great now!

Answer (score 0):

The email is in varchar datatype . you need to put quotes on it

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES ('".$email."')";
```